# Visual Studio missing msvcr120d.dll and msvcp120d.dll error

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 I cant run my exe on another computers because of missing missing msvcr120d.dll and msvcp120d.dll.

I already downloaded vcredist from:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784

I tried MT (Multi-threaded) but same error. :(

Please help I tried everything.

Comment: This also applies to msvcr140d.dll

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are linking against the *Debug* CRT library (indicated by the trailing *d*). Those aren't redistributable, and are only available on systems, where Visual Studio is installed.

The solution is to compile a release configuration. A release configuration links against the *Release* CRT library, that is part of the [Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784), and can be deployed alongside your application.

A release configuration can be built by selecting *Release* from the configuration dropdown list:
[image: Configuration dropdown list]

Comment: Sorry,how can I compile a release configuration?

Comment: I am using VS Community 2015 and facing the same error, "Missing MSVCP120D.dll". Now this happens when I am trying to debug from VS, not even on another computer! Happens when I am trying to use Opencv 310 in a program...

Comment: @bytestorm: You are using an OpenCV build, that's incompatible with your development environment. It is looking for the Visual Studio 2013 debug CRT, but you are using Visual Studio 2015. You can either switch to Visual Studio 2013, or get an OpenCV build that's compatible with Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: @IInspectable I see the problem now. I will then try to first build opencv for VS2015, once. If that doesn't work then i will try vs2013